# multiple file components and false positives with eslint

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, typescript-eslint, false-positive, no-unused-vars

We are [splitting](https://mokkapps.de/vue-tips/split-your-sfc-into-multiple-files) the files into the component.vue, styles.scss and template.html, something like:

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
// Common elements
import Category from '@/components/Elements/Category/Category.vue';

// COMPOSABLES
const localePath = useLocalePath();

// DATA
const session = ref(getSession());
</script>

<template src="./CustomTable.html" />
<style lang="scss" src="./custom-table.scss" />
```

But even that `Category`, `localePath` and `session` are used on `./CustomTable.html` the linter provides this issues:

```sh
3:8  warning  'Category' is defined but never used             @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
6:7  warning  'localePath' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
9:7  warning  'session' is assigned a value but never used     @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I know we could use `eslint-disable`

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
// Common elements
import Category from '@/components/Elements/Category/Category.vue';

// COMPOSABLES
const localePath = useLocalePath();

// DATA
const session = ref(getSession());
/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
</script>

<template src="./CustomTable.html" />
<style lang="scss" src="./custom-table.scss" />
```

But that could lead to truly un-used variables to be ignored

Is there any way to make the linter to search for usages in the linked template file? else what do you suggest we could do about it?

by the way this is our eslintrc.ts

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "no-debugger": "off",
    "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "vue/no-reserved-component-names": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "padding-line-between-statements": ["error", { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "if" }]
  }
}
```

-EDIT-

Could also

```vue
defineExpose({ Category, localePath, session })
```

but I prefer not avoid exposing when not intended